# MongoDB Drivers in screencast

Tags: meteor

http://www.meteor.com/screencast

I watched the video and saw how through the browser are recorded in the data base (blue, green, red).
Is it possible to do this in Linux (Ubuntu)?
There is a MongoDB Drivers or Client Libraries?

Comment: Sure, if autopublishing is on(it's included by default), just open web console in browser and do operations with db. At the first data will place at you own cache called minimongo, after that data will sync up with big database at the server.

Comment: @Denis What is the name of the database on the server?
How to view the record in the local database? I'm recording, but it is not recorded in the local area (minimongo) and on the server. [Screen](http://s017.radikal.ru/i411/1310/30/42b731afe527.png)

Comment: On server is MongoDB. From browser you can view records like yourCollectioName.find({});

Comment: @ArtPip you must properly setup publications and subscriptions for each collection if you aren't using the default insecure/autopublish packages

Comment: @Denis Thank you. You can send this as an answer, I will mention it the best.